# Retrieve specific value from Json in c# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have to retrieve specific value from json. Ex: "id": "217331368373746" in string formate.
below is the json query and my code to acess id=217331368373746

```
{
   "id": "191746304265586",
   "albums": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "217331368373746",
            "created_time": "2012-03-24T20:53:34+0000"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/191746304265586/albums?limit=1&fields=id&after=MjE3MzMxMzY4MzczNzQ2"
      }
   }
}
```

CODE:

```
var jsonalbum = Retrivedata("https://graph.facebook.com/191746304265586?fields=albums.limit(1).fields(id)");
        foreach (var objalbum in jsonalbum["albums"])
        {
            //here what code
        }

    public dynamic Retrivedata(string query)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(query);
        var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream());
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
foreach (var objalbum in jsonalbum["albums"]["data"])
{
   var id = objalbum["id"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you also have a `data` property (array) inside your `albums` list so you would have to do:

```
foreach (var objalbum in jsonalbum["albums"]["data"])
{
   var id = objalbum["id"];
   ...
}
```